# Использование html в базе данных sqlite

Tags: java, android, html, xml, sqlite

В `strings` использовать `html` можно, достаточно поместить тест с `html` тегами между `<![CDATA[` и `]]>`, а дальше вызывая из `strings` в `TextView` подключить `html`, если необходимы больше чем просто стандартные теги - `Html.fromHtml`. Но что если в `TextView` нужно не из `strings` вызывать, а из БД `SQLite`, а текст хранится в отдельном `xml` файле проекта в таком виде:

```
<base>
<start colums="Текст с html тегами №1" />
<start colums="Текст с html тегами №2" />
<start colums="Текст с html тегами №3" />
</base>
```

Как в данном случае подключить поддержку `html` тегов? Например: `<b>, <i>, <font>`..

Comment: Экранируйте все спецсимволы